# Python Grouping - list only the minimum value row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am having an issue with what I can only assume is a simple issue, if anyone might be able to help out with where I have gone wrong I would be most grateful.

Below is the solution I have found searching on stack - unfortunately this isn't what I an looking for:

```
p2all.loc[p2all.groupby('emotion').age.idxmin()]
```

Below is my code, which is almost working as it should but not quite:

```
p2all.groupby(['emotion']).emotion.agg(['count'])
```

my query gives these results:

[image]

All I am now looking to do is only show the minimum value which is Euphoric 658 and none of the others, but after 2 hours of google and stack, I am either completely missing it, or I am searching the incorrect things.

Oddly this is something I can do easily in SQL :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resulting object after using groupby aggregate function is a series. You can simply use series functions to get min or max or whatever you want.

```
series = p2all.groupby('emotion')['emotion'].agg('count')


min_idx = series.idxmin()

min_val = series.loc[min_idx]


print(f" emotion: {min_idx}, value: {min_val}")
```

`(min_idx, min_val)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanks @Mohammad, this nearly solves it, though my results are as follows:
658

This is using: 
    <code>emotion = p2all.groupby('emotion')['emotion'].agg('count') 
    minidx = emotion.idxmin()
    minval = emotion.loc[minidx]
    print(minval)</code>

(apologies, not sure how to use code blocks in replies)

I need the results to be specifically state the name of the emotion and the number, preferably in one line of a f'print statement. Though at this point, I will be happy just to get it to work :)

Comment: @Owen Could you accept or upvote the answer if it helped you. Thanks

Comment: I have upvoted, but because I am new it doesn't show it until I get 15 rep. I haven't accepted it though as I still need a bit more for it to be solved. Many thanks indeed though :)

Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your edit. Thank you for your help. I have now accepted :)